Can I use a water sealer on painted stucco and then paint over that?
I have a masonry house in FL.  8 year old construction on a barrier island 500 yards from the Atlantic.  The house is due for a repaint to match a new addition.  In the past after a hurricane I noticed some rust stains coming through the stucco on the bottom of the exterior walls - ostensibly the rebar got wet and some rust leached through.  The rust stains have since disappeared, but I was wondering if I could use a product like drylok or thoroseal on the first three feet from the ground, and if so, could I then apply the house paint over that?

There are some options for you to consider.
The product can be tinted, but only in a few colors. You could tint the Drylock and use regular exterior latex on the rest of the house.
Some reviews say it can be painted over when allowed to dry properly. However long term results are not available.
Some reviews say it is paintable if sealed with a shellac based primer.
The definitive answer can come from the company; Technical Service Team at 1-800-845-5227 or by email at ugllabs@ugl.com.
